# An integration problem containing a P.D.F. and a score function

Tags: density-function, integral, scoring-rules

Given, a probability distribution function (P.D.F.), $f_{\theta}(x)$ and its score function, $$u_{\theta}(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} log_e f_{\theta}(x) \;\;,$$

how do I evaluate the following integration for any P.D.F., $f_{\theta}(x)$ :
$$\int_{\mathscr{x}} e^{f_{\theta}(x)} \, u_{\theta}^2(x)\, f_{\theta}^2(x) \, dx \; \; ?$$

Here, $x$, which is present underneath the integration sign is actually the **support of x**.

P.S. : Monte Carlo integration method can be used.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answerable, because $u_\theta$ could be almost any function at all.  What can you say about how $f$ depends on $\theta$?

Comment: this can be done via Monte Carlo method of integration. and yes, $f$ does depend on $\theta$ and $x$.

Comment: As soon as you edit the post to make it a clear, answerable question, it will come to the attention of the community, which will vote whether to reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not so sure about my solution, but this is how I think should solve this problem.

$$\int_{\mathscr{x}} \; e^{f_{\theta}(x)} u^2_{\theta}(x) f^2_{\theta}(x) dx $$

$$= \int_{\mathscr{x}} \; e^{f_{\theta}(x)} u^2_{\theta}(x) f_{\theta}(x) f_{\theta}(x) dx $$

$$= \int_{\mathscr{x}} \; W(x) f_{\theta}(x) dx $$
$$\Bigg( \textrm{where}, \;\;W(x) = e^{f_{\theta}(x)} u^2_{\theta}(x) f_{\theta}(x) \Bigg)$$

$$= E\Bigg[ W(x) \Bigg] \cong \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n W(x_i).$$

Here, ($x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$) are a random sample of $n$ observations, drawn from the continuous probability distribution, bearing the P.D.F. $f_{\theta}(x)$.